# Access - Requery quits after 60 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a subform in access that's using a query definition for executing a stored procedure (on SQL Server) as its record source, essentially for the purpose of a search. The user types in an identifier, Access modifies the query definition (`exec [procname] [identifier]`), requeries the subform, and then it *should* populate the subform with the results of the procedure.

Problem is, if after exactly 60 seconds if nothing's come back, it gives in. No errors, no timeout alert, no warnings. Just gives every impression that it's received an empty result set. Stepping through the code confirms it - it hangs around on the `Subform.Requery` line for exactly 60 seconds (I've timed it) and then goes "well that's quite enough of that" and moves on without even alerting an issue. **There is no error handling in this sub** (no dodgy `On Error Resume Next` or anything - if there's any problem at all, it should bomb).

I've copied the query definition straight out of the debugger whilst stepping through the code and fired it in SQL Server Management Studio, and it does work. It just takes longer than 60 seconds.

Why is access throwing in the towel after 60 seconds? And how can I force it to wait for longer?

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/timing_out.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your query in design view. Under the View menu, select Properties.

When the "Query Properties" window appears, set the "ODBC Timeout" property to 0.

By default, it will be set to 60, which means that the query will timeout after 60 seconds. By changing the ODBC timeout value to 0, Access will never timeout.

This property is specific to the query that you are working on. So if you have any problems with other queries, you will need to repeat the same steps on each of those queries.

You can also set it in code by using something like this (you can probably pare this down to just the 1 or 2 lines you need...:

```
    Sub ODBCTimeoutX() 

 Dim dbsCurrent As Database 
 Dim qdfStores As QueryDef 
 Dim rstStores As Recordset 

 Set dbsCurrent = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb") 

 ' Change the default QueryTimeout of the Northwind 
 ' database. 
 Debug.Print "Default QueryTimeout of Database: " & _ 
 dbsCurrent.QueryTimeout 
 dbsCurrent.QueryTimeout = 30 
 Debug.Print "New QueryTimeout of Database: " & _ 
 dbsCurrent.QueryTimeout 

 ' Create a new QueryDef object. 
 Set qdfStores = dbsCurrent.CreateQueryDef("Stores", _ 
 "SELECT * FROM stores") 

 ' Note: The DSN referenced below must be configured to 
 ' use Microsoft Windows NT Authentication Mode to 
 ' authorize user access to the SQL Server. 
 qdfStores.Connect = _ 
 "ODBC;DATABASE=pubs;DSN=Publishers" 

 ' Change the ODBCTimeout setting of the new QueryDef 
 ' object from its default setting. 
 Debug.Print "Default ODBCTimeout of QueryDef: " & _ 
 qdfStores.ODBCTimeout 
 qdfStores.ODBCTimeout = 0 
 Debug.Print "New ODBCTimeout of QueryDef: " & _ 
 qdfStores.ODBCTimeout 

 ' Execute the query and display the results. 
 Set rstStores = qdfStores.OpenRecordset() 

 Debug.Print "Contents of recordset:" 
 With rstStores 
 Do While Not .EOF 
 Debug.Print , .Fields(0), .Fields(1) 
 .MoveNext 
 Loop 
 .Close 
 End With 

 ' Delete new QueryDef because this is a demonstration. 
 dbsCurrent.QueryDefs.Delete qdfStores.Name 
 dbsCurrent.Close 

End Sub
```